# Asyntask doesn´t obtain anything after tabhost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

My app has some activities and all work fine, but there is a problem, when i enter in my "rank" activity (it is based on tabhost) and then i return to the menu and go to "preferences" activity there is another asynctask which doesn´t download the image from a server. It always works, but not in this case...

The whole process is: "rank", here i declare 3 tabs, depending what i do i can see different ranks and i can see (using the same method than in "preferences" activity) the image of each player in rank, then i return (calling before it finish()) to main menu and i go to "preferences" where asynctask starts "downloading" the image but it do it in a very short time (because it doesn´t download the image).

First of all thank you! and to finish i have to say: sorry for my english.

Comment: Can u explain your problem nicely??

Comment: The problem is that if i enter in "preferences" i can download an image using an asyntask but if i enter in other activity (only in "rank") and then in "preferences" it seems that the asyntask is called, and enter in doinbackground but the image is not displayed (and neither downloaded)...

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!! It was a bad written "key" in a intent... Stupid problem... Thank you!!